# Moving away from parameterized getters

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm planning to use an application scoped bean (as a common bean) to return a value of `rowsPerPageTemplate` attribute of [`<p:dataTable>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/paginator.xhtml) like `5,10,15,20` - a comma-separated list of values indicating the page size of `<p:dataTable>`.

```
<p:dataTable var="row" value="#{viewScopedBean}"
    lazy="true"
    pageLinks="10"
    rows="10"
    rowsPerPageTemplate="#{pageTemplate.getCommonTemplate(viewScopedBean.rowCount)}">

    ...

</p:dataTable>
```

The `pageTemplate` bean :

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public final class PageTemplate {

    private static final int pageSize = 10;

    public PageTemplate() {}

    private static String getTemplate(int rowCount) {
        if (pageSize >= rowCount) {
            return String.valueOf(pageSize);
        }

        int sum = 0;
        int pages = (int) Math.ceil(rowCount / (double) pageSize);
        pages = pages >= 100 ? 100 : pages;
        String templateString = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
            sum += pageSize;
            templateString += sum + ",";
        }

        return new String(templateString.substring(0, templateString.length() - 1));
    }

    public String getCommonTemplate(int rowCount) {
        return getTemplate(rowCount);
    }
}
```

The bean and XHTML are self-explanatory. A parameterized method `getCommonTemplate()` is being referenced to by an EL expression `#{}` and consequently being invoked more than once.

Although the logic contained by the method is very cheap, it should not be the best practice to wrap this kind of logic around a getter method in a bean.

Can the code inside the `getCommonTemplate()` method be moved in a place where it is guaranteed to be executed only once (this should not the currently used bean for `<p:dataTable>` - `ViewScopedBean`, since the code contained by the `getCommonTemplate()` method should be shared across all beans that use `<p:dataTable>`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `#{viewScopedBean.rowCount}` is available during view build time (i.e. set in `@PostConstruct`), then you can use `<c:set>` to evaluate an EL expression once and store it in `request`, `view`, `session` or `application` scope (when no scope is specified, it defaults to none scoped and acts as "alias").

```
<c:set var="rowsPerPageTemplate" value="#{pageTemplate.getCommonTemplate(viewScopedBean.rowCount)}" scope="view" />
<p:dataTable ...
    rowsPerPageTemplate="#{rowsPerPageTemplate}">
    ...
</p:dataTable>
```

However, if it's not available during view build time (which is apparently true in your case with `LazyDataModel`), then your best bet is to cache the results in `#{pageTemplate}`.

```
private static final Map<Integer, String> TEMPLATES_BY_ROW_COUNT = new HashMap<>();

public String getCommonTemplate(int rowCount) {
    String template = TEMPLATES_BY_ROW_COUNT.get(rowCount);

    if (template == null) {
        template = getTemplate(rowCount);
        TEMPLATES_BY_ROW_COUNT.put(rowCount, template);
    }

    return template;
}
```

Comment: `ViewScopedBean` is any simple view scoped JSF managed bean. The `rowCount` property is not declared in this bean. Instead, it is directly referenced from `org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel<T>`. In this case, `<c:set>` is referencing to `rowCount` too early before `<p:dataTable>` is iterated over and `LazyDataModel<T>` is initialized. Hence, `rowCount` in the `pageTemplate.getCommonTemplate()` method is always zero (it is not initialized in `<LazyDataModel<T>>` at the time of the `pageTemplate.getCommonTemplate()` method is invoked by the value expression of `<c:set>` - just to my wild guess)

Comment: It works when the `scope` attribute of `<c:set>` is removed in its entirely but the method in the `PageTemplate` bean is invoked multiple times as it did before.

Comment: `rowCount` is still zero. The `getTemplate()` method returns from the first return statement (inside the `if` condition). Hence, no comma-separated string is formed. It just returns the initial value `10` of `pageSize` (since `rowCount` is zero).

Comment: Did you remove the `<c:set>`? It's either-or.

Comment: Is this entire `<c:set>` to be removed? `<c:set var="rowsPerPageTemplate" value="#{pageTemplate.getCommonTemplate(viewScopedBean.rowCount)}" scope="view" />`. What is the value of EL here then, `rowsPerPageTemplate="#{???}"`? Did not understand :)

Comment: It is a lazy load. Sorry, It took some time to get it into my brain. I did not understand a shortcut, "*either-or*" (due to below English level). It is all working fine now. Thank you :)